# Unable to connect to remote server when i call my webservice (using proxy) in Window server 2012

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, httpwebrequest, windows-server-2008

I have issue with my webservice (using proxy ). Everything run smoothly when i debug in my computer . But I get this error "Unable to connect to remote server" whenever i call the webservice in my Window server 2012 VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a proxy is blocking the connection. Do you have Fiddler running? If not, try loading it and closing it to see if that resets the proxy.